# SQL: How to group by column without exploding aggregating value in the table

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate, aggregate-functions

How to transform `table_1` to `table_2` without exploding aggregating values like follows:

```
-- table_1
 a    b
 aaa  1
 bbb  2
 aaa  3
 ccc  4
 ccc  4
 bbb  1
 ddd  4
 bbb  2
 aaa  3
```

```
-- table_2
 a    b   count
 aaa  1   1
 bbb  2   2
 aaa  3   2
 ccc  4   2
 ccc  4   2
 bbb  1   1
 ddd  4   1
 bbb  2   2
 aaa  3   2
```

`count` column is a count of column `a` and `b` and I only know how to get `count` value not expended like the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table_1
GROUP BY a, b
```

```
-- result
 a    b   count
 aaa  1   1
 bbb  2   2
 aaa  3   2
 ccc  4   2
 bbb  1   1
 ddd  4   1
```

Could anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a window function:

```
select t1.*,
       count(*) over (partition by a, b) as count
from table_1 t1;
```

You can use `create table as table_2` if you want to create `table_2` with these counts.